# Problems with Node npm on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, npm, uninstallation

I downloaded node a week ago and it was running fine, except today I realized that the version was far outdated. I tried to uninstall node and npm manually by deleting files (read a different stackoverflow question), but node still runs as well as npm.

How do I successfully uninstall both of them and install the correct versions of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could type

```
which node
```

in your terminal to see where node is installed. Same with npm. Remove those files.
I really like installing node using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).